# Git - merge from specific commit onwards

Tags: git

Say i have a master and a develop branch - develop has a lot of commits that master does not for simplicity sake:

```
Develop:

Commit 1
Commit 2
Commit 3
Commit 4
Commit 5
Commit 6
```

I want to cut a new feature branch from master that does not have any of these commits in develop.

but the tricky part is that I want to merge develop into my feature from commit 3 onwards.

I could cherry pick but in reality there are many, many more commits than my simple example.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You could cherry-pick:

```
git checkout -b newfeature master
git cherry-pick commit2..develop
```

if that syntax isn't supported directly, there, use:

```
git cherry-pick $(git rev-list commit2..develop)
```

<sub>**note:** the first commit in the `a..b` range notation is not included in the list of revisions, thanks Carl</sub>

Otherwise, it looks like a case for `rebase --root ... --onto`. I always look up the specifics in the man page.

Answer (score 0):

If commits 3-6 do not depend on commits 1-2, you can clone the branch and then use interactive rebasing to split the develop branches into two branches, so that the histories look like:

develop1: master commit1 commit2
develop2: master commit3 commit4 commit5 commit6

Then you can merge the two different branches in using merge. Otherwise, you'll have to use cherry-picking as the other answer says. This will work, but you'll lose the history of the branch relationships.

In general it makes sense to create a new branch for each specific topic that you're working on, being more on the finely grained side. Local branches are cheap, and even remote branches aren't that bad. It's a lot easier to organize your trains of thought if you're keeping things on separate branches. It also encourages you to work in a way that has you dividing your problems into independent modular pieces whenever possible, which encourages better system design, improves testability, etc.